# /posts/{ids} reports that it requires an access token, but that's not documented

Tags: support, api

Hitting the following URL:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/25860304?key=<valid key>&filter=!b0OfN.wXSdUuN(&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow
```

I'm getting a HTTP 400 (Bad Request) response with the following content:

```
{
    "error_id": 401,
    "error_message": "This method requires an access_token",
    "error_name": "access_token_required"
}
```

However, the [`/posts/{ids}` endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids) isn't documented as requiring an access token, and the API console doesn't provide an input for one.

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your filter [includes all fields](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter#filters=!b0OfN.wXSdUuN(&filter=default), including info on whether the current user upvoted the post. This information requires an access token to determine the user.

The [docs page for the `post` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post) states that `upvoted` and `downvoted` are private_info.